# Set key value pairs in a combobox

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, tcombobox

What is the best way to set key/value pairs in a combo box?

For example I want to set:

1. Key: T1     Value: test 1
2. Key: T2     Value: test 2
3. Ecc...

Answer (score 2):

The `TComboBox.Items` property is a `TStrings`, which has `AddPair()` and `AddObject()` methods that allow you to associate a `TObject` value with each string.  You can use that `TObject` to store whatever you want.